# How to Programmatically display version of angular2/typescript

Tags: html, typescript, angular2-forms

**How to Programmatically get version of angular2 and render on the page?**

i tried to import { Component,Version } from '@angular/core'; and tried to get the version but did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
console.log(Version.major);
console.log(Version.minor);
```

This should give the major and minor version that you are using

Answer (score 1):

Don't import "Version". Import **VERSION** (uppercase). Example:

version-example.component.ts:

```
import { Component, VERSION } from "@angular/core";

@Component( {
    templateUrl : "./version-example.component.html"
} )

export class VersionExample {
    //Example 1:
    theMajorVersion = VERSION.major;

    //Example 2:
    theMajorAndMinorVersion = `${VERSION.major}.${VERSION.minor}`; //Use backticks

    //Example 3:
    theFullVersion = VERSION.full;
}
```

version-example.component.html:

```
Major version: {{theMajorVersion}}
<hr/>
Major.Minor version: {{theMajorAndMinorVersion}}
<hr/>
Full version: {{theFullVersion}}
```

Output example:

Major version: 5

---

Major.Minor version: 5.2

---

Full version: 5.2.0